# Why is my Flask-SocketIO server not sending messages successfully to my client-side JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, python, flask

I work on a home automation project with raspberry pi3 and flask. I would like to be able to send real-time info that will be displayed on a web page (html + javascript). For this I use the extension flask-socketio but it does not seem to work. Here is an excerpt of my code:

**EDIT:** After a lot of research, I thought it was necessary to create a thread so that the server sends messages to the client while it is processing other tasks. Then I modified my code as below. But I encounter a problem: the client receives a notification only once, when the first movement is captured. It receives nothing when other movements are captured and in my console I have an error of the kind:

> return self.greenlet.switch() timeout: timed out

```
#-*- coding:utf-8 -*-
import eventlet
eventlet.monkey_patch()
from flask import Flask, render_template, send_from_directory, jsonify, request
from flask_socketio import SocketIO, send, emit
import os
import sys
import threading
import time
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
PIN=4
GPIO.setup(PIN, GPIO.IN)

app = Flask(__name__, static_url_path='/static')
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'secret'
async_mode = "eventlet"
socketio = SocketIO(app, async_mode = async_mode) 
thread = threading.Thread()
thread_stop_event = threading.Event()

@app.route('/<path:path>')
def static_file(path):
    return app.send_static_file(path)

class MotionThread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        self.delay = 1
        super(MotionThread, self).__init__()

    def startMotion(self):
        try:
            mouv = False
            while not thread_stop_event.isSet():
                if GPIO.input(PIN):
                    if mouv == False:
                        socketio.emit('motion', "Motion detected", namespace='/test')
                        sleep(self.delay)  
                        mouv = True

                else:
                        mouv = False

        except: pass

    def run(self):
        self.startMotion()

@socketio.on('connect', namespace='/test')
def test_connect():
    global thread
    print('Client connected')

    if not thread.isAlive():
        print "Starting Thread"
        thread = RandomThread()
        thread.start()        

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    socketio.run(app, host='0.0.0.0', port= 5000, debug=True)
```

**FIRST CODE:**

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, send_from_directory, jsonify, request
from flask_socketio import SocketIO, emit, send
import time
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
PIN=4
GPIO.setup(PIN, GPIO.IN)

app = Flask(__name__, static_url_path='/static')
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'secret'
socketio = SocketIO(app)

@app.route('/<path:path>')
def static_file(path):
    return app.send_static_file(path)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template ('index.html')

@app.route('/_startMotion')
def startMotion():
    try:
        motion = False
        while True:
            if GPIO.input(PIN):
                if motion == False: test_message()
                motion = True
            else:
                motion = False
            time.sleep(.3)
    except: pass
    return 'ok'

@socketio.on('motion', namespace = '/motion-socket')
def test_message():
    emit('motion detected', {'data': 'Motion detected'})

if __name__ == '__main__':
    socketio.run(app, host='0.0.0.0', port=5000, debug=True)
```

**EDIT2:** Depending on my first code, the javascript code now looks like this:

```
<script type=text/javascript>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var socket = io.connect('http://' + document.domain + ':' + location.port + '/test');
        socket.on('motion', function(msg){
            alert("Server message" + msg);
        });
    });
</script>
```

I would like to be able to post a message on my web page, whenever a movement is detected. Then an idea of ​​what does not work in my code? I need help figuring out why the thread runs only once. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm not very familiar with SocketIO, but it seems your JavaScript code isn't specifying what URL the socket should connect to.

Here's what your JavaScript should maybe look like instead, based on the example in [Miguel Grinberg's tutorial](https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/easy-websockets-with-flask-and-gevent):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var socket = io.connect('http://' + document.domain + ':' + location.port + '/motion-socket');
    socket.on('motion', function(msg){
        $('#message').text(msg.data);
        $('#message').fadeIn().delay(3000).fadeOut();
    });
});
```

---

Also, your JavaScript seems to be listening for an event with name "motion", but your Python `test_message()` socket function sends the event with the `send()` function, which doesn't allow for specifying an event name, rather than using the `emit()` function, which *does* allow specifying an event name:

> To send events a Flask server can use the send() and emit() functions provided by Flask-SocketIO. The send() function sends a standard message of string or JSON type to the client. The emit() function sends a message under a custom event name.

[Source](https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/easy-websockets-with-flask-and-gevent)

It seems like you'll want the function to look more like this:

```
@socketio.on('motion', namespace='/motion-socket')
def test_message():
    emit('motion detected', {'data': 'Motion Detected'})
```

Comment: I just tested with "emit", and I also specified the URL to which the socket should be connected. But nothing seems to work. The problem is at this level:  `if motion == False: test_message()`. it is that when I detect a movement, the loop remains blocked in the function **test_message**, and the client does not receive any information.

Comment: Do you have a namespace set up? What exactly is the URL the socket is connecting to? And what exactly does your Python code look like now? It sounds like your app is just not set up correctly. Try running the server from a debugger (like the one with PyCharm) or inserting `print` / `console.log()` statements in your Python and JavaScript to see exactly where it's getting stuck.

Comment: I have just edited my code according to the new configuration. I added a namespace, the url in javascript code. But still no results. When I put a `print("Motion detected")` just before **emit**, I see the message once in my console. As if the loop remains frozen

Comment: In the code you currently have in your question, your Python server is emitting an event called 'motion detected', but your JavaScript is listening for an event called 'motion'. That discrepancy may be one thing preventing your code from working.

Comment: I just edited the code again. I added in my javascript code, the line: `<script type=text/javascript src="socket.io.js"></script>`. I had omitted it and after some research I understood that it was necessary to integrate it. Then I retrieved it in the official github repository [github. com/socketio](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io), and I copied it into my static directory... But again, no results.